# how fire upgradeneeded event with out upgrade version of the indedexdb

Tags: javascript, events, indexeddb

i have a question about the event "upgradeneeded".

i need to check the data base every time the user reload the page, but how to fire it with out upgrade the version of the indexeddb, or it's the unique solution ?

```
request.addEventListener('upgradeneeded', event => {
var db = event.target.result;
var planningObjectStore = db.transaction("planningSave", "read").objectStore("planningSave");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"upgradeneeded"` is only fired when you need to change the schema, which you signal by changing the version number. If you're not modifying the schema - e.g. you're just reading/writing to existing object stores - use the `"success"` event instead. Also, there's an implicit transaction within the `"upgradeneeded"` event, so no need to call `transaction()` there.

```
var request = indexedDB.open("mydb", 1); // version 1

// only fires for newly created databases, before "success"
request.addEventListener("upgradeneeded", event => {
  var db = event.target.result;
  var planningObjectStore = db.createObjectStore("planningSave");
  // write initial data into the store
});                

// fires after any successful open of the database
request.addEventListener("success", event => {
  var db = event.target.result;
  var tx = db.transaction("planningSave");
  var planningObjectStore = tx.objectStore("planningSave");
  // read data within the new transaction
});
```

Comment: i try with "read" mode but it doesn't work because we need to write "readonly"

Comment: Oops, thanks! I copy/pasted that, thanks for pointing it out. Since "readonly" is the default it can be omitted.